# Getting the FindClass function pointer from jvm.dll

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to get the function pointer to FindClass method in jvm.dll. Now I did something similar succeffully with the JNI_CreateJVM method but with FindClass its not working.

```
class JVMInitializer {
public:
    static JVMInitializer* getInstance();
    static void destroyJVM();

    static HMODULE m_jvm_dll;
    static JavaVM *m_pJvm;                      
    static JNIEnv *m_pEnv;                      
    static JavaVMInitArgs m_VMargs;
    static decltype(&JNI_CreateJavaVM) m_createJVM_Ptr;     
    static decltype(&JNIEnv::FindClass) m_FindClass_Ptr;


private:
    static JVMInitializer* m_pJVMInstance;              

    JVMInitializer() {};
    ~JVMInitializer() {};
    JVMInitializer(JVMInitializer const&);
    JVMInitializer& operator=(JVMInitializer const&);

    static char JVMInitializer::getPathSeparator();
    bool static create_JVM();
};
```

And then in the create_JVM() method I do this:

```
m_createJVM_Ptr = (decltype(&JNI_CreateJavaVM))GetProcAddress(m_jvm_dll, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
m_FindClass_Ptr = (decltype(&JNIEnv::FindClass))GetProcAddress(m_jvm_dll, "FindClass");
```

The first one works and the program is able to find and call the JNI_CreateJVM method successfully but I get the compilation error in the m_FindClass_Ptr. My guess is I am calling the GetProcAddress for findclass wrong, since its actually a method inside JNIEnv_ struct in jni.h (I might be wrong).

```
struct JNIEnv_ {
const struct JNINativeInterface_ *functions;
#ifdef __cplusplus

jint GetVersion() {
    return functions->GetVersion(this);
}
jclass DefineClass(const char *name, jobject loader, const jbyte *buf,
                   jsize len) {
    return functions->DefineClass(this, name, loader, buf, len);
}
jclass FindClass(const char *name) {
    return functions->FindClass(this, name);
}
......
```

Any help regarding loading the FindClass function pointer will be helpful. thanks :)

Comment: What's the compilation error you are getting?

Comment: I usually don't ask that question, but why do you want that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `JNI_CreateJavaVM` is an actual exported function but `FindClass`is not. `FindClass` is the name of a member in the JNIEnv struct and the VM will initialize that member to a function pointer when it creates an `env`.